# Kile Live Preview not working under Artful 17.10

Tags: 17.10, kile

When i started using kile in willy (15.10), i started directly with 
'kile live preview' after upgrading to Artful when i want to install it with :
`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:kile/livepreview
sudo apt-get update`
I got the message :

> Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kile/livepreview/ubuntu artful Release
>     404  Not Found

I change it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kile-ubuntu-livepreview-artful.list` to use zesty repo `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kile/livepreview/ubuntu zesty main`

run :
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kile`
I get kile live preview installed but when i run it, it crashes, if i run it from terminal i got :

> kile(31690)/kdecore (KLibrary) findLibraryInternal: plugins should not have a 'lib' prefix: "libkonsolepart.so"
>   KCrash: Application 'kile' crashing...
>   KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
>   KCrash: Connect sock_file=/home/me/.kde/socket-dell8/kdeinit4__0
>
> (kile:31690): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: inotify read(): Bad file descriptor
>   Trace/breakpoint trap

Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kile version in `livepreview` is quite outdated. Try downloading latest release from [Debian Sid (unstable) - amd64](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/kile/download)

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/kile/kile_2.9.91-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./kile_2.9.91-4_amd64.deb
```

Although the version says `2.9` it's actually `3.0beta1`. Kile doesn't require upgrading any dependencies, it works fine on Ubuntu 17.10.

Alternatively you can [build Kile from source code](https://kile.sourceforge.io/download.php).

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I used `sudo apt install ./kile_2.9.91-4_amd64.deb`, because the command you given didn't install dependecies.

Comment: @RochdiBoudjehem Right, `dpkg` installs only single package, if necessary you can fix it by `apt install -f`. But your solution is better.